# Dynamic fields with PHP to capture arrays for measure of central tendency

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, forms, dynamic

Im trying to create a form where you can dynamically add fields so you can individually add arrays, for later use them as measure of central tendency like Mean, median, and mode and use of stats_standard_deviation as well.

EDIT: Yes, with this I am capturing data, but how can I get transform the fields to capture arrays? and how do I later use them for operations?

this is what I have so far I got from couple tutorials:

```
  <head>
       <title>Diez</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
       <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       <script src="jquery.min"></script>
       <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
       <div class="container">
            <br />
            <br />
            <h2 align="center">Capture arrays </h2>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <form name="add_name" id="add_name">
                      <div class="table-responsive">
                           <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
                                <tr>
                                     <td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td>
                                     <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>
                                </tr>
                           </table>
                           <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
                      </div>
                 </form>
            </div>
       </div>
  </body>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i=1;
  $('#add').click(function(){
       i++;
       $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
  });
  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
       var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
       $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
  });
  $('#submit').click(function(){
       $.ajax({
            url:"name.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:$('#add_name').serialize(),
            success:function(data)
            {
                 alert(data);
                 $('#add_name')[0].reset();
            }
       });
  });
});
</script>`
```

Comment: ...and your question is?

Comment: how can I get transform the fields to capture arrays? and how do I later use them for operations?

Comment: It already is capturing a 1 dimensional array, because your field's name has `[]` on it.  When it is submitted to a script, it will be interpreted as `$name[0]`, `$name[1]` etc in the order it is received (top to bottom).  If you want to specify the index number, you'll need to do that in your javascript.  `$('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="name['+i+']" `...

Comment: if I say I want to call the array in another php form, should I use the POST?

Comment: You're a little ambiguous there... If you are wanting to access that data by loading another page, you're going to have to persist the data, either in a database or in a session variable.  That's going way past the scope of the current question.  If, however, you are merely wanting to report something (once) that you've calculated from what you've submitted, you would take the results of the POST data, do your logic, and report it back to the browser.  (without persisting data, though, one shot is all you get)